# Adding AWS GameLift policies for uploading new builds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-gamelift

I am trying to upload a new AWS GameLift Linux server using the AWS CLI but I get the following error:

```
 An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateBuild operation: User: arn:aws:iam::------:user/----- is not authorized to perform: gamelift:CreateBuild because no identity-based policy allows the gamelift:CreateBuild action
```

I added the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/GameLiftGameServerGroupPolicy` to my group permissions. I can see in the policy json that there isn't a `CreateBuild` action. It either needs to be added or you can't do it this way.

The AWS documentation is useless and on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/security_iam_troubleshoot.html#security_iam_troubleshoot-no-permissions

it helpfully advises:  `... asks his administrator to update his policies`

My user is the main root user for my AWS account but I have no idea how to resolve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to create a new Policy and add the service permissions. You click on 'create policy' and then choose the 'GameLift' service. I added all the available actions. Seemed to do the trick.

Why did AWS miss this out of the documentation?